# How can I get "Use packet data" Settings in ICS Android

Tags: android

I am developing an application which does some downloading depends on whether the 
user has enabled the option in Settings-> Wireless and network-> Mobile networks -> Use packet data.
I need to check the user has enabled this options.

Please help me to find out how can i get this settings.

For eg to check the roaming mode I use.,

```
import android.provider.Settings.Secure;    
String android_id = Secure.getString(getContentResolver(),
                    Secure.DATA_ROAMING);
```

Thanks in advance 
Deepu

Answer (score 0):

works on 2.3:

```
ConnectivityManager manager = (ConnectivityManager)context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
Method method = ConnectivityManager.class.getDeclaredMethod("getMobileDataEnabled");
method.setAccessible(true);
boolean res = (Boolean)method.invoke(manager);
```

Here I access private method ( boolean getMobileDataEnabled() ) by reflection, it is a not so good practice, but as we know, in Android it, in usual, the only way to implement something (even though CommonWare and other nerds think :)